# setTransformOriginPoint not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt, gestures

I inherited from the `QGraphicsObject` and created a new class that has a pixmap and sets its transform origin point to:

```
setTransformOriginPoint(boundingRect().center());
```

But when I call `setRotation()` on the my class (which is added to a `QGraphicsView` using the scene), the rotation doesn't use the center as the rotation anchor. How can I set the center to be the anchor of the rotation ? Thanks !

More information: calling setRotation() outside of a sceneEvent function it works, but inside a sceneEvent, upon a pinch gesture, the origin point doesn't work.

Comment: I have a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592900/qgraphicssvgitem-positioning-after-rotation. Have you managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Draw pixmap at `QRect(0, 0, pixmap.width(), pixmap.height()`. Use this rectangle for bounding rect also. Use `setPos` to move the item around the scene.  Use `setTransformOriginPoint(pixmap.width() / 2, pixmap.height() / 2)` to set the origin point. These coordinates are in the item coordinates, so they should point at the pixmap's center regardless of the item's position.

Comment: I already tried to use the width()/2 and height()/2, and that is actually the same value as the boundingRact().center(), the problem is that this value isn't respected by the Qt when I call setRotation() after receiving a pinch Gesture event. Thanks !